# Python list contains only digits integer or string

Tags: python

I need to check if a list contains only digits of int or str.

ex:

`[3, 34, "45", 7, "3"]`

would return true

and `["3" "hello", 9]`

would return false

I know that the `.isdigit()` function cannot be used with a list containing int

Comment: Hint: a string contains an integer if it can be successfully parsed by `int`

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? What does _digits of int_ mean, by the way?

Answer (score 6):

Simply try this one-linear pythonic solution:

```
>>> all(map(lambda x: str(x).isdigit(), [3, 34, "45", 7, "3"]))
True
>>> all(map(lambda x: str(x).isdigit(), ["3" "hello", 9]))
False
```

Comment: I like this solution, but I want to provide some clarity. `str(x)` converts any list item to type string and then applies the isdigit() function which returns a boolean. This lambda expression is mapped as an iterator to the entire list and the `all` keyword returns True is all values being iterated over equate to True.

Answer (score 2):

```
your_list = [3, 34, "45", 7, "3"]
def foo(e): 
    try: 
        int(e) 
        return True 
    except ValueError: 
        return False

all(map(foo, your_list))
```